# R combinations split N into sub n

Tags: r, combinations, permutation

I am after an algorithm that will calculate all possible bin sample sizes from an overall sample sizes. So I want to calculate all combinations of n_i with the constraints that the sum(n_i) = N and n_i >= 1.

for example N = 10 and I have 4 bin samples some possible combinations could be

2,3,2,3 another
1,1,1,7 etc

Ideally the function will take two parameters

```
bins = 4
N = 10
```

and return all the combinations, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inherently recursive and can be best solved by using dynamic programming with memoization (since the recursive function with the same parameter values will get called multiple times, it makes sense to remember the already computed values).

Let's define the function `partition(n,k)` to represent the set of all `k-tuples` `(x1,x2,...,xk)` s.t. `x1+x2+...+xk=n` with each `xi >= 1` (partition `n` into `k` nonempty subsets, in other words). The following figure shows how using top-down recursion will encounter too many redundant computations:

[image]

As we can see,  `partition(n,k)` can be computed by combining the results from `partition(n-i,k-1) + [i]` for all `i=1,2,...n-1`. Let's store the value of the function `partition(n,k)` at a table as `D[n,k]` (implemented as `list of lists`).

```
partition <- function(n, k, lst) {

  DT <- rep(list(list()),n*k) # the dynamic programming table as list of lists
  for (i in 1:n) {
    DT[[i]][[1]] <- list(i)
  }

  for (i in 2:n) {
    for (j in 2:k) {
      temp <- list()
      for (m in 1:(i-1)) {
        if (i-m >= j-1) {
          temp <- c(temp, lapply(DT[[i-m]][[j-1]], function(x) c(x,m)))
        }
      }
      DT[[i]][[j]] <- temp
    }
  }

  return(DT[[n]][[k]]) 

}    

partition(10,4,list())

# output
[[1]]
[1] 7 1 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 6 2 1 1

[[3]]
[1] 5 3 1 1

[[4]]
[1] 4 4 1 1

[[5]]
[1] 3 5 1 1

[[6]]
[1] 2 6 1 1

[[7]]
[1] 1 7 1 1

[[8]]
[1] 6 1 2 1

[[9]]
[1] 5 2 2 1

[[10]]
[1] 4 3 2 1

[[11]]
[1] 3 4 2 1

[[12]]
[1] 2 5 2 1

[[13]]
[1] 1 6 2 1

[[14]]
[1] 5 1 3 1

[[15]]
[1] 4 2 3 1

[[16]]
[1] 3 3 3 1

[[17]]
[1] 2 4 3 1

[[18]]
[1] 1 5 3 1

[[19]]
[1] 4 1 4 1

[[20]]
[1] 3 2 4 1

[[21]]
[1] 2 3 4 1

[[22]]
[1] 1 4 4 1

[[23]]
[1] 3 1 5 1

[[24]]
[1] 2 2 5 1

[[25]]
[1] 1 3 5 1

[[26]]
[1] 2 1 6 1

[[27]]
[1] 1 2 6 1

[[28]]
[1] 1 1 7 1

[[29]]
[1] 6 1 1 2

[[30]]
[1] 5 2 1 2

[[31]]
[1] 4 3 1 2

[[32]]
[1] 3 4 1 2

[[33]]
[1] 2 5 1 2

[[34]]
[1] 1 6 1 2

[[35]]
[1] 5 1 2 2

[[36]]
[1] 4 2 2 2

[[37]]
[1] 3 3 2 2

[[38]]
[1] 2 4 2 2

[[39]]
[1] 1 5 2 2

[[40]]
[1] 4 1 3 2

[[41]]
[1] 3 2 3 2

[[42]]
[1] 2 3 3 2

[[43]]
[1] 1 4 3 2

[[44]]
[1] 3 1 4 2

[[45]]
[1] 2 2 4 2

[[46]]
[1] 1 3 4 2

[[47]]
[1] 2 1 5 2

[[48]]
[1] 1 2 5 2

[[49]]
[1] 1 1 6 2

[[50]]
[1] 5 1 1 3

[[51]]
[1] 4 2 1 3

[[52]]
[1] 3 3 1 3

[[53]]
[1] 2 4 1 3

[[54]]
[1] 1 5 1 3

[[55]]
[1] 4 1 2 3

[[56]]
[1] 3 2 2 3

[[57]]
[1] 2 3 2 3

[[58]]
[1] 1 4 2 3

[[59]]
[1] 3 1 3 3

[[60]]
[1] 2 2 3 3

[[61]]
[1] 1 3 3 3

[[62]]
[1] 2 1 4 3

[[63]]
[1] 1 2 4 3

[[64]]
[1] 1 1 5 3

[[65]]
[1] 4 1 1 4

[[66]]
[1] 3 2 1 4

[[67]]
[1] 2 3 1 4

[[68]]
[1] 1 4 1 4

[[69]]
[1] 3 1 2 4

[[70]]
[1] 2 2 2 4

[[71]]
[1] 1 3 2 4

[[72]]
[1] 2 1 3 4

[[73]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[74]]
[1] 1 1 4 4

[[75]]
[1] 3 1 1 5

[[76]]
[1] 2 2 1 5

[[77]]
[1] 1 3 1 5

[[78]]
[1] 2 1 2 5

[[79]]
[1] 1 2 2 5

[[80]]
[1] 1 1 3 5

[[81]]
[1] 2 1 1 6

[[82]]
[1] 1 2 1 6

[[83]]
[1] 1 1 2 6

[[84]]
[1] 1 1 1 7
```

If we want the unique partitions, discarding the order, we can sort each of the lists and then take the unique ones, as follows.

```
unique(lapply(partition(10,4,list()), function(x)sort(x)))
[[1]]
[1] 1 1 1 7

[[2]]
[1] 1 1 2 6

[[3]]
[1] 1 1 3 5

[[4]]
[1] 1 1 4 4

[[5]]
[1] 1 2 2 5

[[6]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[7]]
[1] 1 3 3 3

[[8]]
[1] 2 2 2 4

[[9]]
[1] 2 2 3 3
```